# Animating change in width applied by an iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am creating a skin for an in-game DPS meter, and I have an iteration to collect the data for each combatant

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var combatant = combatants[names[i]];
```

Depending on the combatant's dps, I then use .css() to change the width of a "progress bar" like div.

```
row.find('.bar').css('width', ((parseFloat(combatant.encdps) / maxdps) * 100) + '%');
```

This works fine, however I would like to animate the growth/shrink in the bar's width. If I use animate() instead of css(), the bar is constantly animating (iteration), and I would like to animate changes in width only.

I tried using a css transition "transition: width 2s;" but this seems to have no effect.

EDIT: When changing the inline style="width:32.45%" in the browser inspector I can see the transition, however if the width is being replaced by the for iteration the transition doesn't work.

Comment: Animate() has so many parameters, you'll need to show that call for us to find out why it keeps looping. And to animate the width usign a transition, you need to make sure the element has a defined width to start with, else it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `transition: width 2s;` the animation will take 2 seconds to end, which can seem like it doesn't do anything, if the width should move from 89% to 90%. Try making the period shorter like

```
transition: width .2s linear;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will help you.

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: "Batman",
    score: "100"
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    score: "50"
  }];
  
  for(var i=0; i < people.length; i++){
    
    var row = $("#template").clone();
    row.find(".name").text(people[i].name);
    row.find(".score").text(people[i].score);
    
    row.find(".bar").animate({
        width: people[i].score + "%",
    }, 600);
        
    var container = $("#container");
    
    row.appendTo(container);    
    
  }
  
  $("#template").replaceWith(container);
```

```css
.bar {
  background: #403a3e; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #403a3e, #be5869); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #403a3e, #be5869); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="template">
  <div class="name"></div>
  <div class="score"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

===================

Based on the provided jsfiddle it seems that the css `width` property is not animates since it directly appends to the DOM with a previously defined `width`.

Solution is to use `jQuery` inbuilt `animate` function as follows and remove the css `width` animations.

```
row.find(".bar").animate({
   width: people[i].score + "%",
}, 600);
```

You can see the provided example is working as expected. It is a replica of the logics you added on the jsfiddle.

Comment: When I manually edit the inline style="width: 32.8053%;" I can see the bar grow/shrink like in the snippet. However if the width is being changed by the js iteration there is no transition.

Comment: @Nty Are you constantly changing the bar width inside the for loop. If it&#39;s the case you won&#39;t see the animations since it has no time to animate. You should allow some time to make animation happens. If you want it inside a for loop, just use a timeout in js.

Comment: You can see it in my example as well. I used the setTimeout method to let animation take place.

Comment: This is my iteration, I can't seem to use a timeout that would repeat after every iteration instead of just once. https://jsfiddle.net/80ka9tua/

Comment: @Nty I updated the answer. Just set the width after you append it to the DOM.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work. In addition it sets the width of every bar (in different rows) to be the same.

Comment: Hm.. Let me think

Comment: @Nty Now it should work. I updated the answer with an exact replica and pinpointed the problem. You can mark it as the correct answer and vote up if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks so much, this actually works, however every time the values change as the iteration goes on, the bar animates from 0 as supposed to from where it was. (eg if its 60% intially, and then increases to 80% the bar will grow from 0 again instead of from 60-80) which is the same issue I had initially with using animate()